# How does Perl handle a hash assignment to a scalar variable?

Tags: perl, hash, scalar

Can anyone explain what happened in background for this code?
Code:

```
%d=('sa',1);
$x=%d;
print "$x";
```

Output:

```
1/8
```

Code2:

```
%d=('sa',1,"da"=>2,"daa",3);
$x=%d;
print "$x";
```

Output:

```
3/8
```

Comment: hash buckets used / hash buckets allocated

Comment: This is not generally a useful feature, except to see if the hash is empty or not.

Comment: The fat comma `=>` in your second example is equivalent to a regular comma `,` and is often used in hash declarations for readability.

Comment: Downvoting this question is a disservice to the community. It has a useful title, simple description, and the link to the duplicated question is likely to help people who come from Google.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate: this questions seems to me asking how to assign a hash to a scalar variable; knowing what is actually happening when they try doesn't tell them how to do it correctly

Comment: Thanks @giusti , ysth and xxfelixxx. And giusti your response gives a hope to new learners like me.